# Moq NUnit test System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have an interface:

```
public interface IConfig
{
    // other methods...
    T GetEnum<T>(string name, bool ignoreCase = false, T @default = default(T)) where T : struct;
}
```

Which my SUT uses:

```
public void DoSomething(IConfig config)
{
    var enumVal = config.GetEnum("MyEnum", false, MyEnum.A));
}
```

My test Moq is:

```
var configMock = new Mock<IConfig>();
configMock.Setup(r => r.GetEnum("MyEnum", It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<MyEnum>())).Returns<MyEnum>(r => MyEnum.B);
sut.DoSomething(configMock.Object);
```

When the test runs it fails with `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch.`

The mock works if I **don't** specify the `Returns` clause and allow it to return the default, so the problem appears to be there?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to run by replacing

```
Returns<MyEnum>(r => MyEnum.B);
```

with

```
.Returns(MyEnum.B);
```

Comment: When I tried that I get a compiler error if I tried that which means my sanitized example doesn't correctly reflect my actual code.

The error is:
`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MyEnum' to 'System.Func<MyEnum, MyEnum>'`

Comment: Did you resolve the difference between what you posted and your actual code?

Comment: Unfortunately no; hopefully I will find some more time to track this down!